# Rails from a high-level view: performing calculations on a model value between view and controller

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

This must be a common need but I can't seem to find a definitive answer on the most rubyesque way. I need to create a fairly complex algorithm to dynamically calculate course grades in a rails 4.1 app.

Specifically, I have a model, "course", and whenever an instance of it is displayed in the view, I want to dynamically calculate the current grade (a decimal value, calculated from many course.field values) and display it as a letter value using a switch/case. My assumption was that I could do this in the controller (but it almost seems like it's complex enough to warrant it's own -- module? In C++ I would create a class). At the same time, since it is created dynamically, it seemed like bad form to create a current_grade field for it in the model, so it's not one I can pass back and forth as one of the allowable params (that I know of-- can one pass a variable in the params that is not represented in the db?).

In my initial research I see suggestions of hidden_field_tags and helper_methods and all_helpers and modules and global modules and more. Under time pressure, I dread beginning down the wrong path. Which is the better approach? Or a good high level doc for reference?

As an example, here is one view in which I would like to calculate current grade, compare it to desired grade, and display accordingly.

```
# index.html.erb
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <li>
    <%= my_algorithm_to_calculate_curr_grade(many course.fields used to caluculate) 
    <= course.desired_grade ? "set li to <Color: red>" : "set li to <Color: green>" %>   
    <%= course.course_name %>     
    Current Calculation: <%= display_results_of_previous_calculation %>   
    (Goal: <%= course.desired_grade %>)   
    <%= link_to 'Show', course %>   
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_path(course) %>   
    <%= link_to 'Drop Course Without Penalty', course, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </li>        
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes you can use hidden fields and virtual attributes to post variables in the params that don't exist in the db. Other than that, what is your question exactly? It's pretty vague.

Comment: Thanks! I guess: in general, if you had a 20 line function whose job it was to take an object's numeric attributes from the view, perform calculations on them, and return them to the view, would you put that in the controller or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question if `course.fields` are attributes of Course or different model(s). If all the fields are Course attributes, I would put it as an instance method on Course.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  def calculated_grade
    # fun algorithm
  end
end
```

If course.fields need to be loaded from the database, I'd probably go with a Plain Old Ruby Object (PORO), maybe call it CourseGradeCalculator (put it in app/models, why not? It's business logic)

```
class CourseGradeCalculator
  attr_reader :course, :fields, :grade
  def initialize(course, fields)
    @course = course
    @fields = fields
    @grade = calculate_grade
  end

  private

  def calculate_grade
    # fun algorithm
  end
end

# controller
@course = Course.preload(:fields).find(params[:id]

# view
CourseGradeCalculator.new(@course, @course.fields)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I believe the models fer is the place for it

Comment: Now that I have started down the wrong road and analyzed the function requirements more deeply, I see that it will need data from both the course and assignment models, so your suggestion of putting a PORO in the app/models has become a beacon of hope. Thanks.